# If business logic wants to send an email

Tags: php, architecture, clean-architecture

I'm trying to implement Uncle Bob's Clean Architecture:

[image: Uncle Bob's Clean Architecture]

Everything is ok except the UseCases/Interactors. I need to register a user, so I need `RegisterUser` UseCase. In the concrete *interactor* I implement the `RegisterUser` use case which just create `User` entity and hash its password with `PasswordBroker` port.

After user creation I need to send a verification email. To do this I need to use framework's component. And there are two main problems.

1. I think it has no sense to write *port* for the Mail service, because this port would be just a huge copy/paste abstraction of a framework service
2. Interactor cannot send an email after user creation, because User finally would be stored after Doctrine `flush()` inside controller. There is a risk, when we've sent an email, but User wasn't stored in a DB. It must be consistent.

What's the best approach in this case?

I think we need some kind of *port* that relates to the concrete use case, this port will be called in the end of use case and implemented in *Application Layer* where framework's Mailer and Doctrine are available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. I think it has no sense to write port for the Mail service, because this port would be just a huge copy/paste abstraction of a framework service

I would create a `Notification` interface that I pass to the use case interactor, similar to an `EntityGateway` or `EntityRepository`.

I would design the `Notification` interface in a way that it abstracts from the concrete notification mechanism, e.g. e-mail, messanger, etc.

The `Notification` could then look like this:

```
public interface Notification {
    public void notifyUserRegistered(User user);
}
```

The implementation would be placed in an outer layer, usually the interface adapters layer. Because this is the layer where interfaces of inner layers gets adapted - therefore the name.

Such a `Notification` interface can be easily mocked in a test and this keeps your tests fast. Thus I don't see the notification interface as a huge copy/paste abstraction.

> 2. Interactor cannot send an email after user creation, because User finally would be stored after Doctrine flush() inside controller. There is a risk, when we've sent an email, but User wasn't stored in a DB. It must be consistent.

First I guess you can't enforce both in anyway, because sending an e-mail does not participate in the db transaction. Thus you will still have the consistency problem.

But you usually can register with the active transaction so that you get informed when it completes successfully. This means that the `Notification` implementation would just register a callback that gets invoked when the transaction finished. Then you can send the e-mail.

I don't know how it can be done in php, maybe that is another question here on SO. In Java there are several ways depending on the transaction api you use.

For Spring take a look at [Transaction bound events](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2) or JEE's [TransactionSynchronizationRegistry](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/transaction/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry.html).  Just to mention some if Java developers read this.

Comment: Yes I already did the same thing as you had advised. But the idea with transaction-completion callback seems a little bit confused. It turns out the EventManager can do `flush()` on the persisted entity, so Doctrine will compute a result for the specified entity, so the side effect is excluded.

Comment: What do you think about `EGateway` and `ERepository` at the same moment? Repository will be used as a "collection" with `add()`, `remove()` and `get*()`, `find*()` methods. And `flush()` in the end will compute all the persisted entities. But the Gateway will have `save()` method that will persist and flush the specified entity right now.

Answer (score 1):

This is the upside/downside to using frameworks.  Clean architecture intentionally isolates you from dependencies like this.  This allows things to change out from under you without being affected by that change.  It also allows you to test against an abstraction (writing automated tests against framework code invariably is horrible).

What you need to do is decide whether it is worth compromising the clean architecture to make use of the framework's advantage.  It's a balancing act, and one that we all have to make decisions on a case-by-case basis.  The more a framework does for us, the less control we get, and generally the less architecturally "pure" our application ends up.  But, without frameworks, we have to write code that is essentially wasteful duplication of existing functionality.

Comment: The best choice I've decided to use is to create Bus with delayed commands executing ability. I'll write a `Bus` port. And in my UseCase I will do something like `$this->bus->delay(new SendVerificationMailCommand($user));`. And in controller I will call `$entityManager->flush(); $bus->flush();`. Command handler will be placed in the Application layer, where the framework components are available